# Random patterns all over the place on screen. Activity monitor shows cpu usage is 80% idle... not sure what's going on

Tags: high-sierra

Does anyone know what's going on here? My screen randomly renders these patterns all over the place at random times. OSX High Sierra. When you resize the window, it's gone but reappears soon after.

This problem only started happening recently (after recent High Sierra update)... screen is fine.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried SMC and Nvram/pram reset, does this happen in recovery mode(you can access recovery by rebooting while holding cmd + r down)?

Comment: just tried the nvram reset. it fixes the issue only temporarily but it comes back pretty soon after.

Comment: Have you run AHT/something to stress the GPU and see if that's the issue?

Comment: Turns out it wasn't stressed so much, more of a frame syncing issue I think. When I had the display outputs coming from the same thunderbolt dock, all issues were gone. Issues only persisted when each display came from a separate source i.e. thunderbolt dock && macbook direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... so I found out what the issue was. If you're using a thunderbolt dock and one display cable is connected via the thunderbolt dock, you cannot then connect the other display directly to the macbook. If you do this, the drivers are not capable enough to prevent the pixel tearing effect due to the pictures being slightly out of sync. Once I connected both displays via the thunderbolt dock, it worked fine.